# Objective C firebase check a node exists

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to check whether a node exists in my firebase document. I couldn't find a working solution for the same. My code is given below.

```
_refHandle3= [[[[_ref child:@"DData"] child:deviceId] child:date]  observeEventType:
              FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull   snapshot) {
                 NSLog(@"Processing date - %@",snapshot.key);
             }];
```

I need to do something else when the node is not existing. How can. I check that

Comment: Since `ChildAdded` fires for child nodes, you cannot use it to detect whether a child node exists. Use a `Value` event for that. See my answer here for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213048/checking-for-child-causes-poor-scalability/43214891#43214891

Comment: One more query: Will value listener trigger whenever there is an update. I need to catch the event only once

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once